# Finding a limit of an integral with with varying lower limit

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals

The problem is to find $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}f(t)$, where
$$f(t)=t\cdot \int\limits_t^1 \frac{\cos x}{x^2}\,dx$$

What I've done do far:

1. Concluded that the left-side limit $\lim\limits_{t\to 0^-}f(t)$ doesn't exist, because for any $\varepsilon>0$

$$
\int\limits_{-\varepsilon}^1 \frac{\cos x}{x^2}\,dx
\geqslant
\int\limits_{0}^1 \frac{\cos x}{x^2}\,dx
\geqslant
\int\limits_{0}^1 \frac{\cos (\pi/3)}{x^2}\,dx
=
\frac{1}{2}
\int\limits_{0}^1 \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx
=\infty
$$

2. Found the upper bound for the right-side limit $\lim\limits_{t\to 0^+}f(t)$ using $\cos x \leqslant 1$:
   $$
   f(t)=
   t\int\limits_t^1 \frac{\cos x}{x^2}\,dx
   \leqslant
   t\int\limits_t^1 \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx
   =
   t\cdot\left.(-\frac{1}{x})\right|_t^1
   =
   t\cdot(-1+\frac{1}{t})
   =
   1-t
   $$
   $$
   \lim_{t\to 0}f(t) \leqslant \lim_{t\to 0}(1-t) = 1
   $$

The question is, how to prove that the right-side limit is exactly $1$? I tried finding different lower bounds, but they all turn out to be less than $1$.

Comment: Apply L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, in order to correctly apply Apply L'Hopital's Rule, we need functions to be differentiable in a neighborhood of a point, 0 in this case. But the integral doesn't exist left of 0

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Use L'Hospital and the fundamental theorem of calculus writng
$$f(t)=t\, \int\limits_t^1 \frac{\cos (x)}{x^2}\,dx=\frac{\int\limits_t^1 \frac{\cos (x)}{x^2}\,dx }{\frac 1t }=\frac{-\frac{\cos (t)}{t^2} } {-\frac1 {t^2} }=\cos(t)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does this mean that the two-sided limit also exists? What prevents us to use L'Hospital rule without considering left side separately and get the answer 1 for two-sided limit?

Comment: @Glinka. This is correct.

Comment: but how can two-sided limit exist, if $f(-\varepsilon) =-\inf$ for any $\varepsilon>0$?

Comment: in order to correctly apply apply L'Hopital's Rule, we need functions to be differentiable in a neighborhood of a point, 0 in this case. But the integral doesn't exist left of 0. How to reconcile this?